# CodeIgniter News Tutorial - Parse Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm following the CodeIgniter tutorial (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html), when I get to '[Display the news](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html#display-the-news)' it isn't made clear where to add the second code block:

```
public function index()
{
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

the only way I can interpret the tutorial, is to add it to the News.php controller.

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller 
{

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('news_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        }

        public function view($slug = NULL)
        {
                $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

                if (empty($data['news_item']))
                {
                        show_404();
                }

                $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
```

when I add it at the end of application/controllers/News.php I get a parse error:

```
Parse error: parse error in /server/application/controllers/News.php on line 33
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: parse error

Filename: controllers/News.php

Line Number: 33

Backtrace:
```

if I include it within the News class, I get two PHP errors & a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare News::index() in /server/application/controllers/News.php on line 32
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /server/application/controllers/News.php:32)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 573

Backtrace:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Compile Error

Message: Cannot redeclare News::index()

Filename: controllers/News.php

Line Number: 32

Backtrace:
```

Not sure what else to try?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second code block `function get_news()`should go in the News_model.php file. This is how your final controller & model will look like:

Model: http://screencast.com/t/XQtJpEnSC

Controller: http://screencast.com/t/Kmec1vGh